Getting Delivery Properties of Event subscription From Azure Function
I'm trying to deliver only one Azure Function to listen multiple Blobs.
For this I choose to publish events when something happens on my storage to an event grid.
Then I have a function (isolated) which is triggered by the [EventGridTrigger].
All works well, nevertheless, I am not able to retrieve the headers I've added in the "delivery properties" of my event subscription.

I am only able to inject a CloudEvent, and the FunctionContext which doesn't carries anything interesting.
Is it possible ?
Thanks

Refer https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/35891#issuecomment-1530048916
